# Imagen 2 pisa hover de la imagen 1

Tags: html, css3

Tengo el siguente problema con la animacion donde dejas el cursor en la imagen mas chica y aparece la segunda mas grande:

Mi imagen 1: "perla" es mas chica que la imagen 2 (la 1 tiene hover en css)

La imagen 2: "flores" es mas grande y supuestamente no deberia tener el hover.

Pero en mi css funcionan las 2 con el hover, cosa que no deberia pasar.

Solo quiero apuntar a la imagen 1 para que se inicie HOVER.

Alguna idea?
link editado
http://jsfiddle.net/yy9Rr/44/

```css
/*div BOX*/

#principal .box {
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 60%;
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 63%;
  left: 40%;
  /*1er puntero box*/
}


/*1er imagen dentro del box*/

#principal .box img {
  width: 60%;
  /*size imagen principal*/
  height: 60%;
}

#principal img {
  left: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}


/*2do div MASK*/

#principal div.mask {
  width: 200px;
  height: 212px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -70%;
  left: -20%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#principal h2 {
  /*margin: 20px 0 0 250px;
  position: relative;*/
}

#principal .box .mask h2 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}

#principal .box:hover h2 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}


/*modificacion de la imagen Pre - on hover*/

.box:hover>img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(-1);
  -moz-transform: scale(-1);
  -o-transform: scale(-1);
  -ms-transform: scale(-1);
  transform: scale(-1);
  -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.0;
}


/*2da imagen despues de on hover - su tamaño original*/

#principal .box .mask h2 .nueva {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="principal">

  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/v707VXF.png" class="pre" />
    <div class="mask">
      <h2><img src="https://i.imgur.com/k2miQmk.png" class="nueva" /></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Puedes colocar el código que estás utilizando, no se si fue que no entendí o que pero en el link que envías todo funciona correctamente

Comment: mis disculpas, mal link:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yy9Rr/42/

Comment: Las imágenes están mal ruteadas, no se ven, debes alojarlas en un sitio donde se pueda acceder a ellas por medio del link directo

Comment: Ahi edite el codigo.

Comment: Entonces según entiendo lo que quieres es que cuando haga hover en la img pequeña se muestre la grande y después no se oculte ? Explicación: la img grande no tiene hover, lo que pasa es que cuando te sales del hover de la pequeña todo vuelve a su estado inicial en su css

Comment: fijate si inspeccionas elementos, la imagen grande que al principio esta oculta, tiene hover tambien, no deberia pasar eso.

Comment: Si dejas el cursor mas abajo de la imagen chica, se hace el hover de todas formas. Ese es el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver tu problema debes hacer lo siguiente:

```css
#principal .box {
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 60%;
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 63%;
  left: 40%;
  /*1er puntero box*/
}


/*1er imagen dentro del box*/

#principal .box img {
  width: 60%;
  /*size imagen principal*/
  height: 60%;
}

#principal img {
  left: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 100;
}


/*2do div MASK*/

#principal div.mask {
  width: 200px;
  height: 212px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -70%;
  left: -20%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#principal h2 {
  /*margin: 20px 0 0 250px;
  position: relative;*/
}

#principal .box .mask h2 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}

#principal .box > img:hover + .mask h2{
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}


/*modificacion de la imagen Pre - on hover*/

#principal .box > img:hover{
  -webkit-transform: scale(-1);
  -moz-transform: scale(-1);
  -o-transform: scale(-1);
  -ms-transform: scale(-1);
  transform: scale(-1);
  -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.0;
}


/*2da imagen despues de on hover - su tamaño original*/

#principal .box .mask h2 .nueva {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="principal">

  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/v707VXF.png" class="pre" />
    <div class="mask">
      <h2><img src="https://i.imgur.com/k2miQmk.png" class="nueva" /></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

Comment: Recortando la imagen no soluciona el problema porque el div mask tiene un tamaño fijo de   width: 200px height: 212px;

Comment: Justamente esa es la idea que el otro div sea mas grande, para hacer el efecto de zoom.
El problema es que div mask actua como hover tambien y no deberia pasar eso.

Comment: Ah comprendo, ya te edito la respuesta entonces había entendido mal !

Comment: Ya te edité la respuesta

Comment: Gracias Camilo! xD
Ayudandome ya por segunda vez con mis problemas!

Comment: Vi que aca agregaste z-index 100, es importante?

#principal img {
  left: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 100;
}

Comment: Muy importante, como tu elemento .mask tiene posición absoluta queda por encima de la img, y necesitamos que sea la img la que está por encima. Si la respuesta resolvió tu pregunta te invito a marcarla para que los futuros desarrolladores sepan que fue la solución correcta

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicacion.
La respuesta me ayudo mucho y ya la marque.